# PHP syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)

Tags: php, codeigniter

What's wrong with my code

```
 <?php foreach($query->result() AS $row);?>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row->Qid?> </td>
         <td><?php echo $row->title?> </td>
         <td><?php echo $row->date?> </td>
      </tr>
 <?php endforeach;  ?>
```

Error message : **syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)**
using Codeigniter

Comment: don't confuse `;` with `:`

Comment: Please make sure your model return `data` or `FALSE` also before every foreach make sure that there is any valid data to iterate. (`if (empty($data)) ...`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

change your code :

```
 <?php foreach($query->result() AS $row): ?>
```

> ```
> change ; to :
> ```

OR

you can use this :

```
<?php foreach($query->result() AS $row){ ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row->Qid?> </td>
     <td><?php echo $row->title?> </td>
     <td><?php echo $row->date?> </td>
   </tr>
<?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should  use `:` instead of `;`

```
<?php foreach($query->result() AS $row):?>
                               --------^
   ....
 <?php endforeach;  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are having two errors in your code, with `foreach loop` and with `echo`

```
<?php foreach($query->result() AS $row):?>///here you need to use : instead of ;
  <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row->Qid; ?> </td> // here you need to put ; before  closing tag ?>
     <td><?php echo $row->title; ?> </td>// here you need to put ; before  closing tag ?>
     <td><?php echo $row->date; ?> </td>// here you need to put ; before  closing tag ?>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach;  ?>
```

Comment: Actually not necessary to terminate the line with `;` when terminating with `?>`